# CSS checkbox:checked not working

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-selectors, checked

I am trying to get checkboxes to change the color of some text within a tabel, but it doesn't seem to be working. The :checked attribute doesn't seem to be working. Text is in . Code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.methodoption
{

}
#row1
{
    color: blue;
}
#buyer1 + #row1
{
    color: blue;
}

#buyer1 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #row1
{
    color: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="justify" style="font-size: 23px;"> 
                                Social compliance has changed a lot over the past few years. Several high-profile industry disasters in key sourcing countries like Bangladesh, along with heightened awareness among consumers about where their clothes come from, has prompted stakeholders all across the supply chain, from production facilities to brands and buyers, to rethink their approach to compliance and supply chain security. As part of our commitment to being a responsive and effective social compliance monitoring partner, we at WRAP wanted to get an idea of what some of these changes were and how we can adapt our own program to better meet those needs.</div><br/>
<div align="Center" style="Font-size: 29px;">WE TALKED TO <STRONG>50</STRONG> BUYERS, THOUGHT LEADERS,<br/>AND OTHER STAKEHOLDERS IN THE SOCIAL COMPLIANCE ARENA</div>
<div align="Center"><img src="infogfx.png" height="350" width="900"></div><br/><br/>
<table align="center" width="600" style="background-color: #aaaaaa;"><tr><td align="center"><em><strong style="font-size: 25px;">WHO ARE THEY?</strong></em></td></td>
<tr><td>In exchange for their participation in they survey, we have agreed to keep the identities of those who particiapted anonymous.</td></tr><table>

<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="buyer1" id="buyer1"></td><td>1</td><td class="methodoption"><span id="row1">Stakeholder Expectations</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="buyer2a" id="buyer2a"></td><td>2(tie)</td><td class="methodoption">Factory Compliance/Strengthen Supply Chain</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="buyer2b" id="buyer2b"></td><td>2(tie)</td><td class="methodoption">Corporate Philosophy</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="buyer4" id="buyer4"></td><td>4</td><td class="methodoption">Integrity of Brand</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="buyer5a" id="buyer5a"></td><td>5(tie)</td><td class="methodoption">Risk Management</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="buyer5b" id="buyer5b"></td><td>5(tie)</td><td class="methodoption">Right Thing To Do</td></tr>
</table></form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Daniel Lisik: That sounds awfully like a W3Schools quote... if so, that page probably hasn't been updated in 10 years. Every browser supports it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [General Sibling Selector `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), as its name suggests, selects siblings. Siblings are elements found within the same parent. Your `input` element isn't under the same `td` as your `#row1` element, and therefore isn't selectable.

For this to work you'd need to contain your `#row1` element within the same `td` as your `input` element:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" ... />
    <span id="row1"> ... </span>
</td>
```

Comment: So what should I put, I have tried the "+" and just a space

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to achieve with CSS. `+` also selects a sibling. See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors.